# While using Fabric lib, how to set a cursor during isDrawingMode to a custom cursor file

Tags: cursor, fabricjs

I use Fabric lib and I want to change the cursor to an external cursor file.
I usually do it using the canvas CSS by changing the cursor to the url of the cursor file.
any way to do it in fabric?
I tried: canvas.freeDrawingCursor = 'url(http://www.example.com/MyBrush.cur)'; but it doesn't work.
any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use following syntax to add cursor file as a resource :

```
canvas.freeDrawingCursor='url(http://ani.cursors-4u.net/movie/mov-2/mov130.cur),default';
```

Basically freedrawingcursor is having two arguments when you are dealing with external resource :
1. URL of resource or file
2. type of cursor in that file

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the second arg.

Comment: I thought marking the green V is was need to be done. anyhow I tried to upvote the answer but I do not have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Okey mark it in your account and when you have reputation, than you can upvote the answer